# Enable button when SelectedItem of ListView changes from null and do the reverse

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, wpf-controls

I am working with WPF and trying to change the Enabled state of a button when we selected an Item of a ListView, or in other words, how to trigger the Enabled state of a button when we Select any ListViewItem?

And i am trying to do the reverse thing with another button, or in other words... Can i change the SelectedItem property from the ListView to null when i click in other button if i am using Commands? How?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should either search more thoroughly or at least pay more attention to the related questions which are being proposed when you try to ask a question, i think your question is already being covered by numberous similar ones. (e.g. the first one on the `Related`-stack)

Comment: Changing your question into two questions which both in all likelihood have been answered does **not** make it any better. Besides, you should try to stick to one question anyway...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a [`DataTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx) to disable it when null.

e.g. (`ListView` being named `lv`)

```
<Button Content="Lorem Ipsum">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=lv}"
                             Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Alternatively you could bind the `IsEnabled` property directly and add a [`Converter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) to the binding which returns a respective bool.

---

Example to clear selection:

```
<Button Content="!">
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="lv"
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="SelectedItem">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: Can you help with another thing? If we have another button who is enabled even if SelectedItem isn't null, and we are using Commands, it is possible to when we click in the button the property SelectedItem triggers to null?

Comment: @Miguel: You can hook up an `EventTrigger` to the `Button.Click` and use a `Storyboard` with an [`ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.objectanimationusingkeyframes.aspx) to make a single frame animation to `null`.